# Why am I getting a No such file or directory exception?

Tags: linux, bash, file, io

I have a script to gather metrics and then output the result of that script to a file

This is the command I'am running

```
bash get_metrics > metrics.txt
```

This works

Now I'am looking to append the date on the file

By running

```
bash get_metrics > metrics-$(date +%y/%m/%d).txt
```

After running this command I get this error

```
'zsh:no such file or directory: metrics-2018/12/23.txt'
```

From reading these posts([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344466/bash-script-error-trying-to-write-to-file-no-such-file-or-directory) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404822/shell-script-to-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist)), it seems like the issue is my usage of '/'s - slashes. Bash must think I'am trying to create a a new directory. When I change the slashes to dashes(-), this command works. How can I tell bash that I'am not trying to create any new directories and to treat the dash as part of the filename?

Comment: You simply cannot use slash as a character in a filename. Its only use is as the directory separator.

Comment: Btw: `bash` is not `zsh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use

```
bash get_metrics >> metrics-$(date +%y-%m-%d).txt
```

to avoid the `/` which is a directory separator and `>>` to append.